# AWS Amplify Sign In `currentAuthenticatedUser` returns `User is not authenticated` After Sign In

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, aws-amplify

I'm trying to get the authenticated user details using the AWS Amplify API `currentAuthenticatedUser` but I'm getting `User is not authenticated`.

Here is the code:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
export default function SignIn({ setStatus }) {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const router = useRouter()

  async function signIn({ username, password }) {
    try {
      let signObj = await Auth.signIn(username, password); // returns the result
      let userInfo = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser(); // returns User is not authenticated
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error signing in', error);
    }
  }

  return (
    <h2></h2>
  )
}
```

`signIn` API returns the result but `currentAuthenticatedUser` returns `User is not authenticated`. Any thoughts why it might be happening ?

Answer (score 1):

I resolve this by importing my auth config at the top of the component

```
Amplify.configure({ Auth : {your auth config goes here }})
```

Answer (score 1):

I too found this confusing. I found the best solution is not to expect `Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()` to not return without an error before the `Auth.signUp()` and `Auth.confirmSignUp()` functions are performed.